# Why am i getting an "is abstract; cannot be instantiated" error

Tags: java, interface, abstract

I have created a Square class that is a subclass of an abstract class Shape. I have also created an interface displayCharacters. I am trying to use displayCharacters in my Square class but keep getting this error: "displayCharacters is abstract; cannot be instantiated." Can someone please help me see where my error is or what I have to do to allow this to work?

```
public class Square extends Shape
{
    private String square;
    displayCharacters dc = new displayCharacters();
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Square
     */
    public Square(String square)
    {
       this.square = square;
    }

    //accessor method
    public void makeSquare(String square)       
    {
       for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)  //vertical for loop
       {
           for (int b = 0; b < 8; b++) //horizontal for loop
           {
                System.out.print(dc);
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
       System.out.println();
       this.square = square;
    }
}//end class Square
```

Comment: Interfaces are not meant to be instantiated. If you have a class `Character` that _implements_ the _interface_ `displayCharacters`, then you want to create an instance of `Character` and not of the _interface_ `displayCharacters` as you are trying to do in your code right now …

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to instantiate an interface. It doesn't contains any data or logic.

Interface is just a pattern of accessable methods that overlays the methods, provided by Class. You should add the word 'implements (your interface)' to Class description to connect that interface with Class.
So,

```
Class A {
    void method1() {}  // available in instantiated object
    void method2() {}  // available in instantiated object
    void method3() {}  // available in instantiated object
}

interface B {
    void method3();
    void method4();  
}
```

Connect A & B -> `Class A implements B` and you will be warned by IDE: `Class A must either be declared abstract or implement absract method 'method4()' in 'B'`. That means that if you create an instance (object) of Class A with methods, descripted by an interface: `B a = new A();` you will only have **method3** & **method4** available. And you see now, that method4 is abscent in your class body, so add it there.

And what do we have now:

```
Class A implements B {
    void method1() {}
    void method2() {}
    void method3() {} // available in instantiated object
    void method4() {} // available in instantiated object
}

interface B {
    void method3();
    void method4();  
}
```

That's the key how to write all methods in one class body and to provide several different methods in different situations.